# Where can I do an FAA IPC in Canada?

Tags: faa-regulations, transport-canada

I have an FAA Commercial License and my instrument checkride was completed 8 months ago. Now I am in Canada and trying to convert my license. Problem is the currency of the instrument rating. Transport Canada said they require an IPC check and I want to know if there are any FAA CFIIs here in Canada who I can do the IPC with. I don't want to go back to the US just to do that.

I was reading the [other similar post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/36798/14897) by a user who says he signed an IPC for FAA pilots in Canada. If you are that user and are reading this post please let me know where I can do my FAA IPC in Canada.

Comment: The OP ***quotes*** the suggested-as-duplicate post, so he's pretty clearly aware of it, and it didn't answer his question. Don't see this as a dupe.

Comment: Note that @mongo said he or she signs off approaches, nothing about IPCs. To complete an IPC you will need a CFII.

Comment: This isn't an answer and you may already have looked into it, but... The [Canadian requirement](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/opssvs/managementservices-referencecentre-acs-400-401-001-478.htm#toc64) is to have done an IPC in the previous 24 months, but your checkride was only 8 months ago. Have you asked them if they'll accept the checkride in lieu of the IPC?

Comment: I know the requirements and been searching the FAR/AIM as well and the problem is, the way it is worded in  the FAA FAR/AIM about the IFR currency and Transport Canada is only going by what is written over there which misguided almost every single pilot. When i told transport canada that i dont need IPC until 12 months from my flight test according to FAA, they are just not convinced. There is a grace period of 6 months after your first 6 months of currency period, now the grace period is not mentioned in simple language, thats the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I get this  question a lot.
I am an FAA airplane and helicopter CFI with an Airplane "double eye" the Instrument Instructor and Multi-Engine instructor. In Canada I'm also an airplane ATPL and airplane  flight instructor.

You can see the certificates for any FAA Instructor with an Instrument Instructor rating at the FAA Airman Registry https://amsrvs.registry.faa.gov/airmeninquiry/

Just enter first name ,  last name, click on  the name and you will see all the FAA Instructor certificates. Unfortunately, Transport Canada does not have such a public pilot data base.

Under an agreement between TC and  the FAA, a pilot who holds BOTH an FAA pilot certificate with an instrument rating, and, a Transport Canada pilot  licence with an instrument rating can use the FAA IPC to use their Canadian Instrument Rating.

There are some differences.
(1) The FAA IPC cannot be done entirely in a simulator, all the approaches with the exception of  the circling approach can be done in a simulator.
(2) A Canadian IPC can be done entirely in  an approved simulator.

An FAA instrument instructor is authorized to do Instrument Proficiency Checks for FAA pilots.

If you hold only a Canadian Pilot Licence without both an FAA Pilot Certificate and TC certificate, you can only do your IPC with a TC authorized person.

Here is where it gets interesting.
Whats required for a Canadian Pilot to get an  FAA Pilot Certificate and Instrument Rating.
Not much.

You  need to pass the TC to FAA pilot certificate exam which is probably 25 questions. You also need to pass the TC to FAA Instrument written exam.
You need  a medical and an  application completed.

You also need your identity confirmed by at least an FAA Instructor. Any FAA Instructor can check  a person's identity for the purpose of obtaining a student pilot licence or higher rating.

Its easy enough to do a cross border trip to get your FAA medical  or  you can choose one of the few that exist in Canada. You will need to do the written exams in the USA as there does not exist any FAA examination centre in Canada.

In sum, it can be done very quickly.
In one day, you can do the FAA medical, do  the exams, fill in an application and get your identity confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find a US CFI-AI who can perform a competency check for you.  It can be done in the US or in Canada (in a US registered aircraft unless that CFI holds TC and FAA credentials).

If you are within 6 months of being current, you can do approaches with a safety pilot in Canada. If you are flying a US registered plane, then you will most likely need a US certificated safety pilot.  If you are flying a Canadian plane, then your safety pilot should be a Canadian pilot, acting as PIC for the flight.  You could still log the approaches and simulated instrument time.

In my experience, it will be far easier to find a US CFI in Canada than it is to find a Canadian CFI in the US.  Ask around.  Consider contacting an organization like AOPA if you are a member, or COPA, and asking them for help locating US CFIs.  I would also ask if they have additional guidance because they may have letters from Transport Canada and the FAA which may have policy considerations which might be good to know.

Comment: One additional thought...at flight safety, there were IPs who had multiple country certificates.  If you are near a training hub, you might look into that. It will probably be expensive, but flying a Level D simulator is lots of fun. Practically, however, you should look for a cheap trip to the states, get your IPC done. While you are at it get a flight review endorsement, so you aren't stuck trying to solve that problem later.

Comment: I talked to an CFII from my school and he said I don't have to do the IPC because under 1 year of the last instrument flight test i don't have to go for IPC instead do the regular currency requirement with safety pilot or in the simulator and that also i can do it in CANADA with any school. The problem is the wording in FAR/AIM which doesn't say this grace period. Everyone there is being taught like the way i was told and even in the flight test the examiner ask you this recency question and the answer is IPC after 12 months of initial flight test. PILOTCAFE is the material used for oral exam.

Comment: The issue is whether TC wants you CURRENT or not.  If they want you current, you can still accomplish the approaches, etc. Since you don't have a Canadian certificate you will need a Canadian safety pilot, who will act as PIC.

Comment: For the conversion process TC don't, according to https://tc.canada.ca/en/aviation/reference-centre/advisory-circulars/advisory-circular-ac-no-401-001 §6.4. They require IPC in the past 24 months prior to application.